# Why my Guard doesn't want to call a recursive function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, call

i'm trying to call to do recursive in my Haskell program. I want to call my function every time a element of my list is matching with a word.

My code is compiling without probleme but when i'm trying to execute him, i have this eror

```
haskell: haskell.hs:(27,1)-(30,33): Non-exhaustive patterns in function detect
```

My function where the problem is :

```
detect :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
detect (x:xs) b
         | x == "now" || x == "go" = detect xs (SwapP 0 1 b)
         | x == "stop" = detect xs (SwapP 0 (length b - 1) b)
detect (x:xs) b = detect xs b
```

In x:xs is have my list of words, and in my b, i have a function who the job is to change the position of the words.

But the recursive in the guards are not working.

The weirdest thing of my problem is when i'm trying to do the same but outside my guards, it's working, if i'm doing

```
  detect :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
   detect (x:xs) b = detect xs (SwapP 0 (length b - 1) b)
```

it's working, my first and my last words are changing.

So if anyone have a idea of the problem, you can put a little message. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is with your function `compares`, not `detect`. That being said, your `detect` function does *not* cover the empty list `[]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the function compares IS the function detect, i just made a mistake with the posting, sorry

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Isn't it the fact that `detect` recurses on the tail, but doesn't have a case to match `[]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but i'm not using a empty list, i'm not understanding at all

Comment: @NatkoUndoshy A list is either an empty list, or consists of an element prepended to another list. This is a recursive definition, so even a non-empty finite list must consist of a sequence of elements prepended onto the empty list. You should look into some resources online on how ADTs in Haskell work and how to use pattern matching to define recursive functions, this will help clarify the problem with `detect (x:xs) b = detect xs b`.

Comment: think about how the recursion will end, eventually `xs` will be the empty list which is not handled.

Comment: @karakfa It was my problem (yes, very stupid btw) thanks you guys. My xs was empty at the end, and it was the problem. If anyone want to put the answer of the problem for the validation, he can.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: Always compile with warnings on. GHC does spot the issue at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, my problem was my `xs` list. I was reading all the list recursively and deleting the elements. At the end, my list was without element but my function was still trying to delete & check the content. So, to deal with that, i just added a simple

```
compares [] b = b
```